# Backbone is not fireing events for simple model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I try to save on localStorage some model data (but even try to catch this event, and put to console some text), and it didn't work: no errors, but no events too.

my code of js:

```
 var app = {
     debug: true,
     log: function(obj) {
         if (this.debug) {
             console.log(obj);
         }
     },
 }; 

 //--------------
 // Models
 //--------------
 app.todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         title: '',
         descr: '',
         created_at: Date(),
         completed: false
     }
 });

 //--------------
 // Collections
 //--------------
 app.todoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: app.todo,
     localStorage: new Store("backbone_todo")
 });



 app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('body'),
     events: {
         'click .nav_todo_list': 'todo_homepage',
         'click .nav_todo_editor': 'todo_editor',
         'click .nav_todo_constructor': 'todo_constructor',
     },
     todo_homepage: function() {
         app.router.navigate("todo_homepage", true);
     },

     todo_editor: function() {
         app.router.navigate("todo_editor", true);
     },

     todo_constructor: function() {
         app.router.navigate("todo_constructor", true);
     },
 });

 app.ApptodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#todo_constructor'),
    initialize: function () {
        //this.input = this.$('#new_todo_title');
        var new_todo_title = $("#new_todo_title").val();
        var new_todo_descr = $("#new_todo_descr").val();
        var new_todo_status = $("#new_todo_status").val();
      },
      events: {
        'click #new_todo_save_btn': 'createtodoOnClick'
      },
      createtodoOnClick: function(e){
        console.log("createtodoOnClick");
        app.todoList.create(this.newAttributes());
        new_todo_title.val(''); // clean input box
        new_todo_descr.val(''); // clean input box
        new_todo_status.val(''); // clean input box
      },
      newAttributes: function(){
        return {
          title: new_todo_title.trim(),
          descr: new_todo_descr.trim(),
          created_at: Date(),
          completed: new_todo_status.trim()
        }
      }
 });

 //--------------
 // Routers
 //--------------

 app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         "": "todo_homepage", // Пустой hash-тэг
         "todo_editor": "todo_editor", // Блок удачи
         "todo_constructor": "todo_constructor" // Блок ошибки
     },
     todo_homepage: function() {
         $("section").hide(); //
         $("#todo_homepage").show();
     },

     todo_editor: function() {
         $("section").hide();
         $("#todo_editor").show();
     },

     todo_constructor: function() {
         $("section").hide();
         $("#todo_constructor").show();
     }
 });

 //--------------
 // Initializers
 //--------------   


 $(document).ready(function() {
     app.router = new app.Router();
     Backbone.history.start();
     app.todoList = new app.todoList();
     app.appView = new app.AppView();
     app.apptodoView = new app.ApptodoView();
 });
```

and some part of html:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#/" class="nav_todo_list">todo List</a>
        <a href="#/todo_editor" class="nav_todo_editor">todo Editor</a>
        <a href="#/todo_constructor" class="nav_todo_constructor">todo Constructor</a>      
    </nav>

    <section id="todo_homepage">
        <h1>todo List</h1>
        <section id="main">
            <ul id="todo_list_homepage"></ul>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section id="todo_editor">
        <h1>todo Editor</h1>
        <section id="main">
            <ul id="todo_crud"></ul>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section id="todo_constructor">
            <h1>todo Constructor</h1>
            <label for="todo_title">Title:</label>
            <input id="new_todo_title"">
            <label for="todo_status">Status:</label>
            <select id="new_todo_status" name="todo_status">
                <option selected value="false">Not completed.</option>
            <option value="true">Completed.</option>
       </select>
       <input type="button" id="new_todo_save_btn" value="Save">

    </section>
</body>
```

also you could check fiddle:

http://bit.ly/1nzsP5a

there - console works, but in my example on localMachine: no - what's the problem? What i do wrong?

(you could run it from my dropbox: http://bit.ly/1tLW2N1)

why events are not fireing? maybe someone could help, becouse spend whole day and didn't find solution

when i wrap whole code in:

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

all is ok, but i think that this is a bad practice. How is it right to do?

Comment: instead of $(window).load you can move your script tags to the end of the document body, just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: Never say `el: $('#task_constructor')`, say `el: '#task_constructor'` instead. Don't say `$("#new_task_title").val()` in a view, say `this.$("#new_task_title").val()` instead to prevent your view from accidentally messing with things outside its `el`. Why are you expecting `new_task_title` to be a jQuery object inside `createTaskOnClick` or `newAttributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two major issues with the code you provided.

The first problem is that your Views aren't getting their `el` set.  If you try adding a `console.log` like so:

```
 app.taskList = new app.TaskList();
 alert(app.taskList.el)
```

you will see that taskList's `el` is actually `undefined`.  In general in Backbone you want to define the `el` when you *instantiate* the View, not when you define it.  In other words, instead of:

```
app.AppTaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#task_constructor'),

 app.taskList = new app.TaskList();
```

try doing:

```
app.AppTaskView = Backbone.View.extend({

app.taskList = new app.TaskList({el: '#task_constructor');
```

The second issue I see is that you seem to be misunderstanding how scope works in Javascript.  When you define a variable like this:

```
initialize: function () {
    //this.input = this.$('#new_task_title');
    var new_task_title = $("#new_task_title").val();
```

it will only be available inside the initialize function.  Thus, when you try to use it later:

```
createTaskOnClick: function(e){
    console.log("createTaskOnClick");
    app.taskList.create(this.newAttributes());
    new_task_title.val(''); // clean input box
```

it won't work because `new_task_title` won't exist.  You can fix this by making those variables properties of the `View` instead:

```
initialize: function () {
    //this.input = this.$('#new_task_title');
    this.new_task_title = $("#new_task_title").val();

createTaskOnClick: function(e){
    console.log("createTaskOnClick");
    app.taskList.create(this.newAttributes());
    this.new_task_title.val(''); // clean input box
```